# Need help selecting correct irrigation pump start relay

Tags: amperage

Controller Manual says "Caution: To prevent timer damage, ensure the 24 VAC pump relay current draw does not exceed 0.30 Amps." But relay specs on the Internet, on product packages and in user manuals do not state "relay maximum draw current" or anything else that is even close. I'd like to get a relay with an operating current rating of 2 or 3 amps, but I don't want to "exceed 0.30 Amps" draw for the coil and burn out the timer/controller. How can convert "max 0.30 Amps draw" to a spec that's useful for selecting a relay?

Comment: are you talking about the coil, or about the contacts?

Comment: What relay coil voltage is specified? Remember that the relay coil current is different from the relay contact current capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Relay manufacturers do specify the coil current.

Here's a sample.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Relays are defined by coil voltage , resistance and AC or DC current, if compatible. Some are both AC/DC  with a shaded pole. A pump may draw 300% ~ 500%  more current on startup than rated current so I expect you will find both of these current ratings in and choose a relay contact current rating for such a motor.  Since coils apply torque with power applied a lower voltage relay will require more current. But this system is assumed to switch 24Vac for both pump coil and solenoids.

I doubt you will be using anything near the maximum current rating for the pump relay coil. Just don't consider connecting the pump directly without a relay. They likely have a 1A Reed Relay inside for switching derated for the AC coil.

Assumptions:

24Vac coil  > expect current will be 0.01% to 0.1% of contact current rating
24Vac load < 10A  SPST-NO

Many mounting styles. PCB, baseplate screw terminals, Sockets

[Price expected < $6 but many cost much more, some much less but not in stock.](https://www.mouser.com/c/electromechanical/relays-contactors-solenoids/?coil%20voltage=24%20VAC%7E%7E24%20VAC%2C%2024%20VDC&contact%20current%20rating=3%20A%7E%7E15%20A&relay%20contact%20form=1%20Form%20A%20%28SPST-NO%29%7C%7E1%20Form%20A%20%28SPST-NO%29%2C%201%20Form%20B%20%28SPST-NC%29%7C%7E1%20Form%20C%20%28SPDT-NO%29%7E%7E1%20Form%20C%20%28SPDT-NO%2C%20NC%29%7C%7E1%20Form%20X%20%28SPST-NO%29%7C%7ESPDT&instock=y&sort=pricing&rp=electromechanical%2Frelays-contactors-solenoids%7C%7ERelay%20Contact%20Form%7C%7ECoil%20Voltage%7C%7EContact%20Current%20Rating)